# iOS Push Notifications ASP.NET talking to Azure Mobile Services

Tags: ios, asp.net, azure, push-notification

I have completed the tutorial in

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started-push/

and able to receive push notification on my iPhone. The question is, if my website is ASP.NET, how can I get my website to talk to mobile services? Or it is not possible at all ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely communicate ASP.Net website with mobile service. Download Nuget Package for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service` and add reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobile.service.aspx.

Instantiate MobileService instance using App Key and secret. And start consuming the DBs as service. There are lot of tutorials for this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2014/02/28/windows-azure-mobiles-services-c-backend-en-version.aspx.

Best way to get used to , is download simple TODO app for .net Backed Mobile service and see how that works.

Comment: I have completed the TODO app mobile service and my IOS app can now receive push from there. Thanks for the help

Comment: @cherhan, I was saying just download sample code for C# too!, you will get to know, how to use Azure Mobile Service in server side code, else just use REST service call ( like we do in JS) in server side code -- ( latter is not advisable, just consider as an option).